# Does using _asm code in a C++ program makes the difference

Tags: c++, performance, assembly

I am developing a program that has to be very very fast.

I will make it in C++, and because it has to do a lot of logical operations like XOR, AND or even count the number of 1s in a binary number, I thought it would be a good idea to use `_asm{}` in some parts of the code to do those operations faster. They will be executed millions of times sometimes.

But I don't know if it will really make the difference and worth the effort.

Please if someone tryed it before I will really appreciate your knowledge on the subject.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: *Premature optimization is the root of all evil.* - Donald Knuth. :) First, make it work in C++. Then profile it to find bottlenecks. Then see how to improve your code algorithmically. And only if that isn't enough, try asm.

Comment: To count the number of bits set in a number, you should use a lookup table.

Comment: For logical operations, it usually won't make any difference. There exists instruction to count number of 1s in binary number, but it depends whether CPU supports the instruction or not - so it is better to use bit fiddling hack to achieve this.

Comment: @user315052: not necessarily. If the CPU has a single-instruction popcount, that might well be better. It could be accessed either via asm, or via a specific compiler extension where available (`__builtin_popcount` on GCC, `__popcnt` on MSVC, in both cases read the manual before using).

Comment: @SteveJessop: I just tried it, the difference in performance is in the microsecond range on my i7 system, but in favor of GCC built-in. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A million ops when the processor clock is a few billion per second is not often a big deal.

So code it in simple C/C++.  Test it.  Profile it.  If it's really too slow and the profile shows a hot spot, turn up optimizations to maximum for that spot and test again.  If it's still too slow, disassemble the optimized code and see if you *think* you can do better than the compiler.  If you think so, go ahead and insert your `_asm {}`.  Be prepared for this carefully handcrafted code to run slower. It happens a lot.  If you *do* achieve the needed speedup, put the assembler in `#ifdef`s so that you can chuck it when the next processor rev is issued. Read: Assembly code is so expensive to write and maintain that it's almost always a bad idea.

Comment: thank you all for your answers and comments! thank you alexey too for the tip about the premature optimization

Answer (score 1):

In my experience doing a little assembler only really helps when you can use the SSE functionality, or indeed a specific new instruction like popcount or crc

From the projects I elevated to unreadability;

```
normal code to ASM =  10% faster, 50 times more unreadable code
suited code to SSE = 500% faster, 75 times more unreadable code
```

So I'd suggest to make your application first, find out what it actually slow and only when all else fails try some asm/sse.

Comment: gcc has builtin functions for all the SSE functions. These can be cleaner than an _asm section.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good idea. It won't significantly improve speed, but it will kill your ability to compile directly for X64 processors which *will* hurt your performance. If you really want to use Asm, look into [Asmjit](http://code.google.com/p/asmjit/) which supports x86/x64.

Comment: Why can't you compile for x64 if you have inline assembly in your C++?

Comment: Inline ASM isn't typesafe and your pointers will get mangled.

Comment: @Dave : Visual C++, at least, only supports inline asm for x86.

Comment: Or just assemble it separately and link it in - you can still do that.

Answer (score 0):

Modern compilers will reduce your C++ code into fairly concise assembly instructions for the target machine you compile it for.

I would say that for most programs, it will not be worth the investment from a purely performance perspective.

It can be a good learning opportunity to get a closer understanding of the underlying hardware!